# Get access token using refresh token with native application client id

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

How to regenerate the access token using refresh token through C# or PowerShell using native application client id?

Having the following inputs:

```
$RefreshToken = "refresh_token"  
$ClientId= "client_id"
```

I have found many ways to regenerate access token using refresh token, but all those are using web app client id and client secret.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you use native application, we will use silent auth([grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant)). It will just return the access token not the refresh token.

I guess you use web application [code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) to get the access token and refresh token.

If you use this way, it must need the client secret and refresh token to generate the access token.